Category Product Page with Full Page Cache
I have customized the catalog price rule to apply different prices for separate customer groups. However, I'm experiencing an issue with the full page cache: the category page does not refresh the product prices when I log in with another account, and I need to clear the cache for it to work.
How can I make it work without having to clear the cache every time?

Dont know about your setup on cache on the site, but Magento basically uses the X-Vary header to identify each customer group for the same page and generate different caches for each case.
Make sure your caching system is interpreting the header as part of the cache identifier. See this thread related to faslty for more information.
